# How to put php array into a html form?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

```
$countryList = array(
    'Russia'        => 'Moscow',
    'US'        => 'United States');
```

I have this array that I am trying to generate onto a hmtl form that will have an output as such.

```
<select name='country'>
    <option value='0'>Russia - St.Petersburg</option>
    <option value='1'>United States - Dallas</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Anything will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Your $countryList data does not match with your sample data you are displaying in your SELECT HTML snippet. The "value" part of the OPTION tag is going to have to be sourced from the array as well.

Answer (score 1):

With a simple loop, and `array_flip/array_keys` to get a map of indexs for the country:

```
<?php
$countryList = [
    'Russia' => 'Moscow',
    'US'     => 'United States'
];
$countryKeys = array_flip(array_keys($countryList));
?>
<select name='country'>
<?php foreach ($countryList as $country => $city): ?>
    <option value='<?= $countryKeys[$country] ?>'><?= $country ?> - <?= $city ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

**Result:**

```
<select name='country'>
    <option value='0'>Russia - Moscow</option>
    <option value='1'>US - United States</option>
</select>
```

*Russia - St.Petersburg* and *United States - Dallas* is not in the list as it's not in the array.